# Calibration PTZ camera with OpenCV's calibrateCamera

Tags: python, opencv

I have N images from a PTZ camera with some point correspondences in each frame.

The problem is the images are taken at different zoom.

I am wondering how to use `cv2.calibrateCamera` for these N images so that some parameters are fixed and some not.

I would like these parameters to **NOT** be fixed:

- `fx=fy` can change from image to image. (zoom with `cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO` for simplicity)
- rotation vectors to change from image to image

I would like to fix these parameters for all images:

- optical centers ( cx,cy)
- camera position as translation vectors `tvecs`

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/calibration-ptz-camera-with-opencvs-calibratecamera-how-to-fix-certain-parameters-across-frames/13693

Comment: followup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578852/why-are-rvecs-and-tvecs-different-for-every-view-in-opencvs-calibratecamera