# Why are rvecs and tvecs different for every view in OpenCV's calibratecamera?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm struggling to understand the real meaning of `revecs` and `tvecs` in the output of `cv2.calibrateCamera`. As I understand them, together they define the pose of the camera, meaning position and orientation of the camera.

However, if I pass multiple views shot from the same camera to `cv2.calibrateCamera` I get `rvecs` and `tvecs` for every view. Shouldn't they be the same if the camera didn't move?

My homography matrix for the first image is defined by

```
K = mtx
R = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs[0])[0]
T = tvecs[0]
RT = np.concatenate((R,T),axis=1)
H = np.dot(K, RT)
```

And I can see that it projects correctly. The way I understand homography it should stay the same for every image as the camera is not moving. However if R, T are changing H will change too.

It seems like I'm missing something very important about the way `rvecs` and `tvecs` are defined in OpenCV.

Comment: if you neither moved the camera, nor the pattern (the image will stay the same with some noise), you should see nearly identical rvecs and tvecs. During calibration it is assumed that the pattern stays stationary and the camera moves. So when you move the pattern, he calibration thinks that the camera moves and the pattern stays stationary.

Comment: I totally missed that. I assumed the pattern is moving and the camera is stationary. That would explain why they would be different for every shot..

Comment: if you instead want to know the pattern pose, you can just invert the rvecs and tvecs, or use solvePnp on the points.

Comment: My main problem is this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76571442/calibration-ptz-camera-with-opencvs-calibratecamera

Comment: Essentially though even with this new definition of `rvecs` and `tvecs` I think the problem statement would be the same. If the camera is not moving and only rotating, only `rvecs` should change, correct?

Comment: how did you try to reach the pure camera rotation? Did you rotate the pattern? That's not pure camera rotation, because the origin of the coordinate is a different one. See this image: https://ibb.co/HqNbFDp A is the initial cam/pattern pose, origin is the center of the pattern. B is pure pattern rotation with the camera being the origin. C is the same pure pattern rotation, but the pattern being the origin and interpreting the camera being moved. You can see that the camera is both, moved and rotated from the camera origin. D is pure camera rotation with camera being origin.

Comment: you cant find a single calibration for PTZ. You will need and individual calibration for every zoom "value".

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/calibration-ptz-camera-with-opencvs-calibratecamera-how-to-fix-certain-parameters-across-frames/13693

Comment: @Micka, thanks for your answer and the image. TBH I'm still a bit confused about what physically `tvecs` and `rvecs` are. The world coordinate system in my case stays the same and the pattern is not moving. The camera is stationary as well. It is just allowed to turn. I'm trying to understand how `tvecs` are related to the position of the camera and how `rvecs` are related to the rotation of the camera.

Comment: As for zoom, I agree with you. My intention is to approximate zoom with different focal length values.

Comment: Why cant you calibrate your camera with a single zoom (moving camera and/or pattern) and, if zoom can be handled by handled by focsl length, just change the focal length entry during your application?;?

Comment: I don't have access the camera. I'm working with a footage.

Answer (score 1):

In calibration, there is no world coordinate system.

For each picture, there is only the frame of the *pattern* (*object*) and the frame of the *camera*, related by one transformation (per picture).

You decide if you have a common camera frame (pattern moving) or a common pattern frame (camera moving). This does not matter for the calibration.

Docs say:

> performs a change of basis from object coordinate space to camera coordinate space

(object = pattern)

The corresponding transformation matrix would be written as

[image: 1]

because that is how matrices and vectors compose. You can line them up like dominos, where the frames match. If you wanted to transform a point from object-local to camera-local, this is the calculation:

[image: 3]

And it can be built from applying `cv.Rodrigues()` to obtain a 3x3 rotation matrix, then combining that with the translation vector, into a 4x4 matrix.

[image: 2]

That transformation implies that if you rotate the pattern around its model origin, the tvec should not change, and that a tvec having +X would correspond to the pattern being in the right half of the space in front of the camera (and +Y in the bottom half).

If you want to transform from camera-local coordinates into object-local coordinates, you need to invert the transformation.

Comment: Ok. So does this mean that the position of the camera in the pattern coordinate system is -np.transpose(R)@tvecs? Which would mean that if the camera stays in the same place, this multiplication needs to stay the same rather than just tvecs, correct?

Comment: I don't think in terms of R and t separated. I think in terms of 4x4 matrices. I highly recommend it, unless you want to sprain your brain and mine too. -- The pose of the marker, in the camera's frame, is `T`. the pose of the camera, in the marker's frame, is `inv(T)`. -- inv(R) == transpose(R), that's right. -- I do not think that the assertion in your first question is true. a simple 2D situation shows that. it _might_ be `transpose(R) @ -tvec` (note the minus) but I won't vouch for that.

Comment: if the camera stays in the same place... and what else? doesn't rotate? does rotate? if it rotates, then its position in marker space would stay constant. I don't get that question.

Comment: by the way, I don't have a drawing, as your bounty requests.

Comment: Thanks for replies @Christoph. I think I'm slowly getting it :)

Comment: To be more precies, I'm working with hockey footage. The field markings serve as a chessboard as they have exact location, and never move. The camera zooms, rotates left/right,  up/down, (potentially little roll, but doubt it). But the essential location of the camera stays the same. And I wanted to somehow use that information for my calibration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254394/discussion-between-mike-azatov-and-christoph-rackwitz).

Answer (score 0):

`rvec` and `tvec` allows to map points in WORLD coordinate system to CAMERA coordinate system. If you change your world coordinate system origin or orientation (which is probably the case if your world coordinate system is aligned with a chessboard and the chessboard is changing orientation/position in each frame), then it will change  `rvec` and `tvec` too even if the camera did not physically change position.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I keep my WORLD coordinate system the same. So the pattern stays in the same place but the camera is zooming and rotating while staying at the same position. So I'm trying to understand what would be `rvecs` and `tvecs` in this scenario.